# Should it be possible to select content from a child element?

Tags: polymer-1.0

Should it be possible to select content from a child element in Polymer 1? Can't find anything about it in the docs, but this doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">


    <dom-module id="my-element">

        <template>
            <content select="#aaa"></content>
        </template>

        <script>
            HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
                Polymer({
                    is: "my-element"
                });
            });
        </script>

    </dom-module>

</head>

<body>
<my-element>
    <div>
        <div id="aaa">zzzzzzzzzzz</div>
    </div>
</my-element>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No way !! everything were changed in Polymer 1.
This docs will help you a lot: [Polymer Elements docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/)

Comment: 2Đam Lê Đình: Could you please point to exact location? Can't find anything but "The <content> element supports a select attribute which filters nodes via a simple selector." Nothing is said about that is should work on top level elts only. In many cases it would be really handy to get elts from the deep.